How to attach object to a rigged object so that it keeps being attached to the same place always? Even when moving the rig
I have a cylinder (tunnel) made in Blender. It has a rig containing 3 bones:

I export it into Unity. With the "Animation Rigging" package and the "Damped Transform" component in it, I add a rig to the cylinder in Unity so that the cylinder can be moved like a worm:

I am also using a custom shader made in shader graph for the cylinder's material.
Question:
What I would like to do, is attach a sphere to the end of the cylinder. So that:

It is attached to the cylinder, and not the bones. If the sphere is attached to the bones, it will move smoothly because of the damped transform. I
When exporting into Unity, I want to keep using the shader graph for the cylinder's material, but the sphere should have a different material.

This is what it should look like:

How can I do this?
